# Can i login web site with chat bot messenger?

Tags: node.js

I have a questions, can i and every one using a chat bot to login a web site ( any website ) , enter the username and password of that website to login it and take information back the chat bot, can i make it ?, Thank you for reading.

Comment: Yes, you can. But, welcome to Stack Overflow, might I suggest you take a read at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before posting.

Comment: ohhh thank you so much, my English is not good and this is a first time i ask, thank you !